# spark throws java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kafka/common/TopicAndPartition

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

when I use spark-submit command in Cloudera Yarn environment, I got this kind of exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kafka/common/TopicAndPartition
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.introspect.BeanIntrospector$.com$fasterxml$jackson$module$scala$introspect$BeanIntrospector$$listMethods$1(BeanIntrospector.scala:93)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.introspect.BeanIntrospector$.findMethod$1(BeanIntrospector.scala:99)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.introspect.BeanIntrospector$.com$fasterxml$jackson$module$scala$introspect$BeanIntrospector$$findGetter$1(BeanIntrospector.scala:124)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.introspect.BeanIntrospector$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(BeanIntrospector.scala:177)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.introspect.BeanIntrospector$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(BeanIntrospector.scala:173)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$map$2.apply(TraversableLike.scala:722)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:108)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.map(TraversableLike.scala:721)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.introspect.BeanIntrospector$$anonfun$3.apply(BeanIntrospector.scala:173)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.introspect.BeanIntrospector$$anonfun$3.apply(BeanIntrospector.scala:172)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:251)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:251)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
...
```

The spark-submit command is like:

```
spark-submit --master yarn-cluster \
        --num-executors $2 \
        --executor-cores $3 \
        --class "APP" \
        --deploy-mode cluster \
        --properties-file $1 \
        --files $HDFS_PATH/log4j.properties,$HDFS_PATH/metrics.properties \
        --conf spark.metrics.conf=metrics.properties \
        APP.jar
```

note that, TopicAndPartition.class is in shaded APP.jar.

Comment: are u able to see the class using jar -tvf APP.jar | grep -i TopicandPartition ?

Comment: Can you show us your build.sbt? Does it have `spark-streaming-kafka` included?

Comment: yes, when I `jar -tvf APP.jar |grep -i Topicandpartition`, I found it, because I've already depended on the kafka_2.10-0.8.2.1.jar, and the spark-streaming-kafka is also added. But still the problem is there.

Comment: @J.Y.Wang- How did you fix this issue. I'm also facing same issue like you faced previously.

Comment: @kit I'm facing the same issue, can you let me know the jar that you used to resolve the error.

Comment: @user1050619- This issue caused by version incompatibility. I used spark-streaming-kafka-assembly_2.10-1.4.1.jar file. Make sure that your version of kafka, spark, scala and zookeeper are compatible with each other. For this refer https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/streaming-kafka-integration.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After using some methods, it turns out that the issue is caused because version incompatibility. As @user1050619 said, make sure the version of kafka, spark, zookeeper and scala are compatible with each other.

Answer (score 0):

Please try adding the Kafka jar using the **--jars** option as shown in the example below:

```
spark-submit --master yarn-cluster \
    --num-executors $2 \
    --executor-cores $3 \
    --class "APP" \
    --deploy-mode cluster \
    --properties-file $1 \
    --jars /path/to/kafka.jar
    --files $HDFS_PATH/log4j.properties,$HDFS_PATH/metrics.properties \
    --conf spark.metrics.conf=metrics.properties \
    APP.jar
```

Comment: I've already added this into my  --jars /home/kafka_2.10-0.8.2.1.jar , but it still has the same problem.

Comment: spark-submit --master yarn-cluster \
        --num-executors $2 \
        --executor-cores $3 \
        --class "APP" \
        --deploy-mode cluster \
        --properties-file $1 \
        --files $HDFS_PATH/log4j.properties,$HDFS_PATH/metrics.properties \
        --conf spark.metrics.conf=metrics.properties \
        APP.jar

Comment: @J.Y.Wang were you able to resolve this error, I have the same issue.